# Angular2 ng-select itemlist inside a ReactiveForms issue for Array of array items

Tags: angular

I'm finding difficulty to get data for `ng-select`

```
<ng-select [allowClear]="true"
  [items]="tempArrayUoM[i]"
  formControlname="uom"
  [active]="initialUoM[i]"
  placeholder="UoM">
  </ng-select>
```

Can someone help how to get the Array of `tempArrayUoM[i]` - can be passed here?
It gives me an error while executing

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]
```

It works fine if I use without the index - `[items]="tempArrayUoM"` but unfortunately, I need to use the array of arrays here. I have a dropdown which depends on another dropdown inside a ReactiveForms;
[image]

Any workaround for this approach also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i am not sure whether it will work or not but just try. Onclick declaring array inside tempArray and initializing that tempArray as source

```
  <ng-select [allowClear]="true"
  (click)="tempArray = tempArrayUoM[i]"
  [items]="tempArray"
  formControlname="uom"
  [active]="initialUoM[i]"
  placeholder="UoM">
  </ng-select>
```

dont forget to add  `public tempArray : any;` in the TS file

Comment: My problem lies when adding more rows with that "add more lines" button. This solution seems some change but not working when adding more rows. I need to get different tempArrayUoM element for every rows and so used the array..